# temperature profile on axial direction of a chamber

Tags: matlab, visualization, comsol

I have a task to plot average temperature profile at each cross-section in the axial direction of a combustion chamber. I have $x$, $y$, $z$ coordinates data in excel as well as the corresponding temperature according to the rows, example ($x=1$,$y=1$,$z=1$, temperature = 500°C). I have around 25000 rows of it. I have also run a simulation in COMSOL using eigenfrequency study.

1) From Matlab, I'm trying to create multiple 2-D meshgrids or slices in the axial direction, then from each slice calculate the average temperature according to the grids and area then plot up the average temperature values according to the z coordinates.

2) or I could create a volume from the set of points using Delaunay or voxelization then do multiple volumetric slices and from the slices calculate the average temperature values.

or is there a better way to compute? like in COMSOL?

Comment: Why don't you just compute a slice of your mesh?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an interpolation function (see [interp3](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp3.html)) to estimate the temperature at each position in a cross-section. Set the extrapolation value to NaN so that points outside your chamber do not contribute.